# Pause in android

Tags: android, flash, android-webview, onpause

I have developed a game in which i need a `pause` in any single `button click` event. I am confused because I have use `swf file` and sound and much `resource`.

As shown, when you pause the screen it will goto sleep mode and the `resume button` is in front of you.

How can i do this?

[image]

Comment: What are you using to create this surface canvas,View,surfaceview or GLsurface view

Comment: IS this complete page from WebView?

Comment: no its part of android component as well as flash

Comment: Then i have to say sorry as i donot have knowledge in flash

Comment: I would say, this has less to do with android but with flash

Answer (score 4):

You could save all the required details in the activity's [onPause](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) method.

When the button for pausing is pressed, you could start one more activity (maybe a [dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) saying the game has been paused).

Resume the game using the onResume method of your activity.

Comment: can you  give one single example?

Comment: @Dr.nik : You can find examples of onPause and onResume in this example http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex3.html

Comment: He isw dealing with flash not normal activity

Comment: @ingsaurabh you are right, but i also havent any knowledge about simple activity can you give me simple example so i can handle primaryly simple and for flash content i will handle

Comment: @Dr. Nik AFAIK you cant handle flash content through android coding, what I guess u r using webview to run a already made game if I am correct then you are in problem

Comment: I dont know how to communicate with flash file from java code or vice-versa

Comment: can you tell me without flash content?    simply

Answer (score 1):

For this If the Activity is running and user has pressed the pause button and that time you can call the function which can pause your resources.

This includes 
1. Pausing of Media file which is being played this you can do with the help of MediaPlayer API
2. Animation of the view you can stop
3. Notification sound you can stop with the help of Notification API

Comment: when user press the pause button. you can pause the sound file which was playing, pause the animation this you can achieve by mediaplayer object which you have used for playing the media files

Answer (score 1):

Pls First Understand the Hierarchy of the activities from here : [MediaPlayer | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#pause())

```
To pause call the function:        public void pause() 
To Start/Resume call the function: public void start()
```

Run the media file in the background in a Service. See the detail code here :

[Resuming Service in Activity and destroying them on destroy | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720774/android-resuming-service-in-activity-and-destroying-them-on-destroy)

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use this in your game Activity, 
this is how I pause my game in webView with flash

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
gameView = (webView) findViewById(R.id.wView);
    if (hasFocus) {
        try {
            Class.forName("android.webkit.WebView")
                    .getMethod("onResume", (Class[]) null)
                    .invoke(gameView, (Object[]) null);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        gameView.resumeTimers();
        gameView.loadUrl("javascript:setflashfocus()");
    } else {
        try {
            Class.forName("android.webkit.WebView")
                    .getMethod("onPause", (Class[]) null)
                    .invoke(gameView, (Object[]) null);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        gameView.pauseTimers();
    }
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
}
```

maybe you cn launch another activity for this to execute